# How to access the graphic node of a treecell

Tags: javafx, treeview

This screenshot

[image]

shows a pretty simple implementation of a treeview where I used a custom treecell made up of a flowpane with 5 labels.  The flowpane extends to the edge of the treeview (highlighted unused flow pane space in red).

What I want to be able to do is resize the labels to take up all available flow pane space.  Ideally each treecell(label in the flowpane) would be able to be independently resized.  I haven't been able to do this in the custom tree cell and/or cell factory because the width of the flowpane isn't known at creation time (at least I haven't been able to determine it).

As far as I have been able to determine the tree cells aren't directly available through the treeview.  I have attempted to save the cells in the cell factory at creation for use at a later time but there are 48 cells created just to show the 5 that are shown in the screenshot and I'm not sure which of those 48 represent those on the screen (presumably the last 5).

So I guess the easiest way to ask the question is, how can I access the flowpane of the tree cells (and by extension the labels)  so that I can calculate and set the label widths?

Comment: The bottom line is that you can't, and should never need to, access the actual cells other than in the cell factory. Probably you can achieve what you're trying to do with an `HBox` with appropriate settings. Post a [MCVE] showing what you're trying to do. It might also help to explain more fully what the actual desired behavior here is: for example, in the screenshot all labels in each column are the same width. Is that a requirement? If so, a `TreeTableView` is probably better than a `TreeView`.

Comment: James_D, thanks for the edit.  Yes this actually started out life as a TreeTableView but the customer wanted to try another approach.  Yes the columns are all the same width, I marked up the fxml to do that but the desire was to have the columns resize by some yet unknown criteria.  Hopefully your response will be enough to return to the TreeTableView conversation.

Comment: If you want all the cells in a given column the same width, that would be extremely difficult without using a `TreeTableView`. If you want them resizable by the user, I suppose it may be feasible to use `SplitPane`s in the tree cells, and have a single `ObservableList<Double>` for the divider positions. For each cell, register a listener with the list to update it's split pane divider positions from the list, and register a listener that updates the list when the user changes the dividers (somehow making sure you don't get caught in infinite loops...).